# Why ngx-doc-viewer is not displaying pdf file(file is on local disk) in angular10?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `angular10` in which i have to display a `PDF` file as a `preview`. So for that i am using `ngx-doc-viewer`. My component is look like this

component.html

```
<ngx-doc-viewer [url]="inputFile.filePath" viewer="mammoth" 
  style="width:100%;height:60vh">
</ngx-doc-viewer>
```

component.ts

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
reader.onload = (_event) => {
  this.inputFile.filePath = reader.result;
}
```

angular.json

```
scripts : [
 "node_modules/mammoth/mammoth.browser.min.js"
]
```

When i upload any `.doc,.docx,.xlsx` file so that it loads that file in `chrome` perfectly but when i try with `ngx-doc-viewer` so it is giving an error in `chrome's console`

`Unsupported viewer: 'mammoth'. Supported viewers: google, office.`

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: if you want to show only pdf then you can check the link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984988/unable-to-show-blob-url-in-pdf-viewer-ng2-pdf-viewer-in-angular-10', however if  you want to show docx and other format then ngx-doc-viewer is the only option but it does not work as you wanted.