# Unable to show blob url in "pdf-viewer" => "ng2-pdf-viewer" in Angular 10

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, pdf

I have an API which is returning uploaded file as blob. When I try to bind `src` with blob URL then it does not show anything, however, when I try to bind direct URL then it can show PDF file. Here is my code given below.
**My TS code**

```
downloadFile(fileData: Fileuploader) {
        this.tempBlob= null;
        
        //Fetching Data File 
        this.apiservice.getDownloadfile(fileData).subscribe(
            (retFileData: any) => {
                this.tempRetFileData = retFileData;
                this.tempBlob = new Blob([retFileData], { type: this.contentType });                    
            },
            (err: Error) => {
                
            },
            () => {                             
                const blob: Blob = new Blob([this.tempBlob], { type: this.contentType });       
                const fileName: string ='ilvsna.pdf';
                this.myBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            }
        );
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <pdf-viewer [src]="myBlobURL"
              [render-text]="true"
              [original-size]="false"
              style="width: 400px; height: 500px"
  ></pdf-viewer>
```

**Note:** if I set myBlobURL URL to 'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf' then it can display

Comment: Can you see your pdf when you insert `window.open(this.myBlobURL);` just after `this.myBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`.

Comment: yes it open the blob in the new tab, but I want show the blob inside the `pdf-viewer` @N.F.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. You can use `ArrayBuffer`. @N.F. Code is correct, however, you said that you got error in the line =>   `this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);`

So, change the line into => `this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer);`.
Finally, your ts code should look like below=>

```
downloadFile(fileData: Fileuploader) {
        this.tempBlob= null;
        
        //Fetching Data File 
        this.apiservice.getDownloadfile(fileData).subscribe(
            (retFileData: any) => {
                this.tempRetFileData = retFileData;
                this.tempBlob = new Blob([retFileData], { type: this.contentType });
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = () => {
                    this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer);
                };
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.tempBlob);                                    
            },
            (err: Error) => {
                
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Let me check you process.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

**ts**

```
    pdfSrc: Uint8Array;
    
    downloadFile(fileData: Fileuploader) {
        this.tempBlob= null;
        
        //Fetching Data File 
        this.apiservice.getDownloadfile(fileData).subscribe(
            (retFileData: any) => {
                this.tempRetFileData = retFileData;
                this.tempBlob = new Blob([retFileData], { type: this.contentType });
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = () => {
                    this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer);
                };
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.tempBlob);                                    
            },
            (err: Error) => {
                
            }
        );
    }
```

**html**

```
 <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
              [render-text]="true"
              [original-size]="false"
              style="width: 400px; height: 500px"
  ></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: In the line of  this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result); it gives me an error " No overload matches this call. => Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBufferLike'." Details => Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<number>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<number>'

Comment: Do you have the line `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.tempBlob)` ? The method should be `readAsArrayBuffer`.

Comment: it is there. I just use you code exactly as you provided.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please modify to `this.pdfSrc = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer);`.

Comment: thank you it helps me a lot because I was getting the file but I wasn't able to show it  in the currect way.
Actually I'm planning to use the tempBlob variable in case that the user wants to download the file, so I won't have to do another request.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with window.URL.createObjectURL of my return blob file from service:
-- ts file

```
this.obuService.getObuDocument(obuId, fileId).subscribe(
  (data: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data.body);
    this.src = url;
    this.viewPDF = true;
  }
);
```

-- service

```
getObuDocument(obuId: number, fileId: number): Observable<any> {
const options = {
  observe: 'response' as 'body',
  Accept: 'application/pdf',
  responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'
};
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/' + obuId + '/upload/' + fileId, options)
  .pipe(catchError(err => { throw err; }));
```

}